# What does this mean for rows and columns?

Tags: pandas

I know that

```
df.iloc[-1] shows only the last row,
```

Comment: It shows only the last 10 rows

Comment: like `df.tail(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for list, same principe is used here.

So

```
df.iloc[-10:,:]
```

show(select) last 10 rows, same ouput is if use [`DataFrame.tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html):

```
df.tail(10)
```